# Best way to store one table with 50 million rows

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, csv

So, i have a task to parse from api a very simple table with 6 columns, which have about 50 million rows. What the best way to write and store it? I think, that csv will be very slow on write/reading

Im using python for this task. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Well if your goal is to keep it for as long as possible the answer is surely to chisel it into stone tablets as they will not corrode like digital mediums.  That's my quippy way of saying, there are many ways to store data, the BEST way depends on your goals and what you want to do with the data.  RDBMS, NoSQL, CSV files are all options -- but you would need to give more background for someone to help you!

Comment: First of all i need the fastest way to write and read data row by row. I dont need access by  a key. The problem is count of rows - more than 50 millions ...